# Change image position on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, position

I don't know very much about coding, but I would like to be able to make it so when I click one of the "test" buttons, the image moves. I would like it to be a variable, so that it is constantly checking the variable (I have no idea how to use variables), and at any given moment, when variable = number, it is in a specific position I have designated. And when I click test 1, that variable goes up by one, and when I click test 2, it goes down by one. And at any given variable from 0-10, there is a specific place the image should be for each number. And once the variable reaches 11, the variable will instantly reset to 0 as if in a loop. It can include HTML, CSS and Javascript, sorry if this is confusing I really am a noob at coding :(

This is all the code I have so far, it really isn't helpful but I thought I should add it anyway.

```
<img id="img01" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/8372/products/tattly_triangle_yoko_sakao_ohama_00_1200x1200.png?v=1575322215" height="300">

<button id="test1" type="button">test 1</button>
<button id="test2" type="button">test 2</button>
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: the movement of the image is somewhat related to the value incremented/decremented? How should it be moved? Show your attempt

Comment: Hello. WHat you are trying to do is not very complicated. But here, on StackOverflow, we do not make code functionality for free ( only maybe on very very easy and fast solutions )  We help you debug/improve your code. So you have 2 choices : 1. do your research, learn, try to find a solution. If you fail ( no problem ) come here again and show us your effort. What have you tried. OR 2. Go on freelancing websites and pay someone to do the work.effort for you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code below. I hope this example will help you to undestand a block move principe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>moved image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                <img class="image" src="" width="50" style="left: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="button" type="button" id="left-button" onclick="moveLeft()">Left</button>
        <button class="button" type="button" id="right-button" onclick="moveRight()">Right</button>

        <style>
            .wrapper {
                position: relative;
                width: 500px;
                min-height: 200px;
                background-color: yellow;
            }

            .image {
                position: absolute;
                top: 40px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 70px;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            'use strict'

            const getNumber = function(str) {
                return parseInt(str, 10);
            }

            const transformToString = function(num) {
                return num + 'px';
            }

            const SHIFT = 10;   
            const MARGIN = 10;
            const element = document.querySelector('.image');
            const LEFT_MARGIN = getNumber(element.style.left) - SHIFT * MARGIN;
            const RIGHT_MARGIN = getNumber(element.style.left) + SHIFT * MARGIN;

            const moveLeft = function() {
                if (getNumber(element.style.left) > LEFT_MARGIN) {
                    element.style.left = transformToString(getNumber(element.style.left) - SHIFT);
                }
            }

            const moveRight = function() {
                if (getNumber(element.style.left) < RIGHT_MARGIN) {
                    element.style.left = transformToString(getNumber(element.style.left) + SHIFT);
                }
            }
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```